# Variable bitrate for AAC - how to reach it?

Tags: ffmpeg, audio, framerate

I tried encoding audio stream into AAC with a *variable* bitrate mode — I followed the advice from [FFmpeg VBR Settings](https://slhck.info/video/2017/02/24/vbr-settings.html) and changed my original option `-b:a 128k` to `-q:a 1.3` in this original command

```
ffmpeg -channel_layout stereo -i sc2.avs -b:a 128k -ar 24000 -ac 2 sc2.mp4
```

But I still obtained a *constant* audio bitrate.

Output from MediaInfo:

> ```
> Audio
> ID                                       : 2
> Format                                   : AAC LC
> Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
> Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
> Duration                                 : 1 min 26 s
> Duration_LastFrame                       : -29 ms
> Bit rate mode                            : Constant
> Bit rate                                 : 119 kb/s
> Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
> Channel layout                           : L R
> Sampling rate                            : 24.0 kHz
> Frame rate                               : 23.438 FPS (1024 SPF)
> Compression mode                         : Lossy
> Stream size                              : 1.23 MiB (8%)
> Default                                  : Yes
> Alternate group                          : 1
> ```

The Any Video Converter (the old version 3.5.8), which internally uses FFmpeg, convert the same input into VBR mode:

> ```
> Audio
> ID                                       : 2
> Format                                   : AAC LC
> Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
> Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
> Duration                                 : 1 min 26 s
> Bit rate mode                            : Variable
> Bit rate                                 : 75.3 kb/s
> Maximum bit rate                         : 142 kb/s
> Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
> Channel layout                           : L R
> Sampling rate                            : 24.0 kHz
> Frame rate                               : 23.438 FPS (1024 SPF)
> Compression mode                         : Lossy
> Stream size                              : 778 KiB (9%)
> Language                                 : English
> Encoded date                             : UTC 2019-12-19 13:30:13
> Tagged date                              : UTC 2019-12-19 13:30:13
> ```

How to reach VBR audio output?

(I need it because of `Dissolve()` function in AviSynth source file produces horrible sound for CBR, whereas it's nice for Any Video Converter's VBR audio output.)

Comment: Don't you need to specify which audio encoder to use? ie, `ffmpeg -channel_layout stereo -i sc2.avs -c:a aac -q:a 1.3 -ar 24000 -ac 2 sc2.mp4` If I do it I get variable bit rate audio

Answer (score 2):

According to the wiki, you are likely to get worse results with the default AAC encoder when using VBR. See: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC

One suggestion would be to use `libfdk_aac`. The other would be to demux the audio, re-encode it using a different encoder, and then remux that file back in to the video using ffmpeg.